# Is Hibernate Criteria API stable for future usage?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I mostly use Hibernate criteria API in my previous project. I found Hibernate criteria Expression is already deprecated!

Is Hibernate Criteria API stable for future usage?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Expression.html

Comment: I don't think they will remove it, but I would bet that there won't be manu evolutions and enhancements, because JPA2 now has its own criteria API. So I think all the efforts will go into this API rather than the Hibernate proprietary criteria API.

Comment: Thank for your valuable answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its deprecated but they have provided **Restrictions** instead. But make sure you make the proper choice between **HQL** and criteria when fetching data in hibernate. I like HQL because its simple, flexible and powerful. Read more about hql [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Comment: I think criteria is better for filtering cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, things do get deprecated. If it's marked as such then don't use it. But if there is no note about deprecation - it's not deprecated. Only fortune teller can tell what happens in future. You can try to read forums and see if there is any discussion but I don't think criteria api is going away or undergo signifficant change.